# No me muestra los datos del datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables, codeigniter

Buenas estoy trabajando en codeigniter para tratar de mostrar los datos de una base de datos en un datatable pero esto me salta con un error que no e logrado resolver para que puedan entender mejor mi problema les muestro mi controlador

este es mi controlador

```
 public function lisForm() {
    $tu = $this->session->userdata("sess_tu");
if ($tu == "ADMINISTRADOR") {    
} else {
    header("location: " . base_url() . "inicio");
}
    $table = "fn_for_dt()";
    $primaryKey = 'id_for';

    $columns = array(
        array('db' => 'id_for', 'dt' => 0),
        array('db' => 'item', 'dt' => 1),
        array('db' => 'tipo', 'dt' => 2),
        array('db' => 'titulo', 'dt' => 3),
        array('db' => 'codigo', 'dt' => 4),
        array('db' => 'uni_adm','dt' => 5),           
        array('db' => 'fec_rec_int', 'dt' => 6),
        array('db' => 'num_for_apr','dt' => 7),
        array('db' => 'tiempo_asig_act', 'dt' => 8) ,           
    );

    //Condiciones adicionales para el WHERE
    $filtroAdd = " id_for  <> 0 "; // 

    //Parámetros de conexión
    $pg_details = array('user' => USUDB, 'pass' => CLADB, 'db' => NOMDB, 'host' => SERDB);
    echo json_encode(
        SSP::simple($_GET, $pg_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $filtroAdd));
}
```

y este que esta aqui es mi js que es donde sospecho se encuentra el error pero simplemente no logro verlo

```
$('#lisForm').DataTable({
"stripeClasses": ['odd-row' , 'even-row'],
'aaSorting': [],
'scrollCollapse': true,
'scrollX': true,
'fixedColumns': true,
'processing': true,
'paging': true,
'pagingType': 'full_numbers',
'serverSide': true,
'language': {
    'url': base_url + 'public/json/language.spanish.json'
},
    "ajax": base_url + 'formatos/lisForm', 


});
```

y el error que me sale cuando intento verlo es este

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Class 'SSP' not found

si alguien sabe que puede ser agradeceria su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedo dejar comentarios por ser nuevo, asi que respondo:

https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

Bajate eso e incluílo en el controlador, al parecer es la clase que te falta